# An interesting dice question on counting probability

Tags: probability

> How many rolls of two dice are needed so that the probability of
> double six occurring at least once is at least $50 \%$?

### Attempt.

Notice that probability of double six $\frac{ 1+1}{6^2} = \frac{1}{18}$.

Let $n$ be the number of rolls of the dice. So,

$$ P(at \; least \; one \; double \; six \; in \; n \; throws) = 1 - P(no \; double \; 6) = 1 - (17/18)\cdot(17/18)\cdot...\cdot (17/18) = 1- (17/18)^n$$

Therefore,

$$ 1 - (17/18)^n \geq 0.5 \iff 0.5 \geq (17/18)^n \iff \frac{\ln .5 }{ ln (17/18) } \leq n \iff n \geq 12 $$

So, atleast 12 are needed.

Is this a correct approach??

Comment: $6^2$ is a small enough sample space that you can easily list all its elements using pencil and paper. Try it, then count how many elements you have. If you have listed each double number twice, and every other element the correct number of times, you will have more than $36$ elements listed.

Comment: I am not saying this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699707, since you have contributed a different solution attempt, but that question has a good title (it helped me quickly identify it as similar to yours) while your title is nearly useless. Please try to put more specific titles on questions, including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but the probability of a double $6$ is $\frac 1{36},$ not $\frac 1{18}$.  When you roll the first die, the probability of a $6$ is $\frac 16$.  Assuming you get that the chance of another is also $\frac 16$, so by the multiplication principle the chance of a double $6$ is $\frac 1{6^2}$

Comment: if die 1 is 6 and die 2 is 6 is different that die 2 is 6 and die 1 is 6

Comment: "if die 1 is 6 and die 2 is 6 is different that die 2 is 6 and die 1 is 6"  Uh, no it's not.  It is exactly the same.

Comment: (6,6) is the exact same thing as (6,6).  There is only one way to get a double 6-- if both die 1 and die 2 are both sixes.  Writing them down in different orders so $d_1 = 6; d_2=6$ vs $d_2=6; d_1 = 6$ doesn't make them different any  more that "Albany is the capital of New York and penguins eat fish" is different from "Penguins eat fish and Albany is the capital of New York".